# What does 1c1 in diff tool mean?

Tags: linux, diff

I ran diff with two files and got the following output:

```
1c1
< dbacaad
---
> dbacaad
```

What does this mean? My two files seem to be exactly the same.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To answer the question you raised in the title:  1c1 indicates that line **1** in the
first file was **c** hanged somehow to produce line **1** in the second file.

In practical terms: They probably differ in whitespace (perhaps trailing spaces, or Unix versus Windows line endings?).

Try `diff -w file1 file2`, which will ignore whitespace.  Or `cmp file1 file2`, which
will tell you how many bytes into the file the first difference occurs.

Comment: After adding -w, it did return no diff. I look through the two files. There is no whitespace but only one nextline character. Is that going to differ in windows and linux as well? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Windows and Unix use different line ending character sequences, and this will show up in a normal `diff`.

Comment: A one-up for the cmp recommendation. A good tool I'm adding to my doctor's bag.